# Как получить данные из SQLite один раз?

Tags: php, sqlite

Из базы данных получаю данные по $click_id (id товара).

Все работает корректно если в базе данных $click_id встречается один раз, что делать если в базе данных один и тот же $click_id встречается несколько раз?
Сейчас выводится информация ровно столько раз, сколько одинаковых $click_id в базе.

Как вывести один раз информацию из базы, если в ней несколько одинаковых $click_id?

Мой код:

```
//обращение за данными по id товара
$results = $db->query("SELECT * from items WHERE item_id=$click_id");

//вывод полученной информации о товаре
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {

$response = preg_replace('~(<title>.*</title>(.*</head>)|(?=</head>))~si', 
$response = preg_replace('/<head([^<>]*?)>(.+?)<\/head>/is', '<head$1>
<base href="' . curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL) . '">$2 
<link rel="canonical" href="http://' . $urls . '/'. $click_id .'"/>
<!-- Open Graph -->
<meta property="og:locale" content="ru, ru_RU">
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://site.ru/up/'. 
$row['image'] .'" />
<meta property="og:image:alt" content="' . $row['title'] . '" />
<meta property="og:title" content="' . $row['title'] . '" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://' . $urls . '/'. $click_id .'" />
</head>', $response);
}
```

Comment: что это вообще?

Comment: Мне после head нужно вставить Open Graph на лету, получив данные из базы. Сейчас Open Graph может дублироваться по 4-5 раз.

Comment: ну если вам нужно взять только первую строку из выбранных в БД, то  1) добавьте в запрос `limit 1` 2) уберите цикл `while`. обычно всю логику делают до того, как начинается вывод контента, тогда и подобных костылей писать не придется.

Comment: Здорово, работает. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для управления количеством записей в результирующей таблице используется оператор `LIMIT`. Этот оператор записывается в самом конце запроса и имеет следующую конструкцию:

```
SELECT ... ... ... LIMIT [offset, ] count
```

Тут используются два параметра:

`offset` - это номер строки в результирующей таблицы (от 0), от которой необходимо отсчитывать записи

`count` - это число, которое означает то, сколько записей из результирующей таблицы необходимо отобрать, начиная от offset.

Параметр `offset` не является обязательным, если его не записывать, то отсчет записей в таблице будет стартовать с нуля. Рассмотрим примеры.

```
SELECT * FROM student LIMIT 1; или SELECT * FROM student LIMIT 0, 1;
```

В Вашем случае:

```
"SELECT * from items WHERE item_id=$click_id LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$results = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * from items WHERE item_id=$click_id");
```

Попробуйте с   DISTINCT выполнить запрос